# ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home

Tags: android, react-native

[image]
here is my error that showing when i run ./gradle --version

[image]
here is my java -version 17.0.2 that is set.

Answer (score 5):

1. You find the java PATH: `java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep 'java.home'`
2. The result like this: `java.home = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home`
3. Add the line in you bash file (for me: ~/.zshrc): `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home` (the path result above)

Comment: For me the `~/.zshrc` part was not needed. When I tried to run with it, I got `permission denied` error.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `PATH` environment variable. It should contain the path to your Java installation. After finding the installation directory set your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to this path (but without the trailing /bin).